# Why do I get errors from my first template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Why do I get these errors every time I try to replace a current template.
[/Resources/WebServerSecurityGroup/Type/GroupDescription] 'null' values are not allowed in templates

Also, below is my .yaml code.

```yml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: My First Template in CloudFormation Course
Resources: 
 WebServerInstance:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties: 
    ImageId: ami-0c1bc246476a5572b
    InstanceType: t2.micro
    Tags:
     -
      Key: Name
      Value: Web Server
     -
      Key: Project
      Value: CloudFormation Step By Step
 WebServerSecurityGroup: 
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties: 
    GroupDescription: 
    SecurityGroupIngress: 
     - 
       IpProtocol: "tcp"
       FromPort: 80
       ToPort: 80
       CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0" 
    Tags: 
     -
      Key: Name 
      Value: Web Server Security Group
```

Answer (score 1):

[A value for the property `GroupDescription` on the `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` is required](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#cfn-ec2-securitygroup-groupdescription), but you left it empty in your YAML specification of the `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup`.

You must specify a string of not more than 255 characters there which describes your security group informally. This property must not be empty/null.